# How to prevent x-axis values ranging from least to greatest?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[I am unable to prevent the x values from going least to greatest and I need them in a specific order, is there such a way to do this in Python?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDJy7.png)

[This is what the order of the x values needs to be instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4wY6.png)

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You want your x-values as categorical values.

Comment: What kind of plot is this?

Comment: You can also cast your values to strings (i.e. `plot(['1', '5', '2'])`) and then these will be treated as categories on the x-axis and labeled as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot them with "default" x values and change the tick labels.

```
plt.plot(Y)
plt.xticks(ticks=range(len(Y)), labels=X)  # where X is your list with the order you want
```